# Javascript set variable to input, then navigate to page

Tags: javascript, html, variables, input

I have an input where, theoretically, the user types in a box, presses enter, and the browser navigates to the input text with .html appended at the end. I originally was trying to deal with submitting the form, but the form no longer submits after I added `preventDefault();`. What I have now doesn't seem to set the variable to the form element, and then doesn't get to the URL part. My code:

```
<form name="answerarea">
<input type="text" name="input">
</form>
```

then

```
function sendanswer( e ) {
if ( e.keyCode === 13 ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var answer = this.document.answerarea.input.value;
    if (answer) { this.location.href = answer + ".html"; }
    }       
}

document.answerarea.input.onkeypress = sendanswer;
```

Any clue why it's not working? Thanks.

Comment: Get rid of the `this.` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the function on the `keypress` event of input, so `this` will refer to the input, which does not have an `input` or `location` object inside it..

modify your code as follows:

```
function sendanswer( e ) {
 if ( e.keyCode === 13 ) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var answer = document.answerarea.input.value;
 if (answer) { window.location.href = answer + ".html"; }
 }       
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked. Also learned quite a bit about javascript from this endeavor.

Comment: too bad SO has a chat option, i've seen new users asking friends to upvote their copy pasted answer and downvote the original. ~ LOL

Answer (score 2):

The `this` keyword would most likely point to the current element, which would be the input field. Try this instead.

```
function sendanswer( e ) {
    if ( e.keyCode === 13 ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var answer = this.value;   
        if (answer) { 
            window.href = answer + ".html";
            return false;
        }
    }       
}

document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].addEventListener("keyup", sendanswer);
```

The context of this will change depending on how sendanswer is called. ex : with `.apply` or `.call` will allow you to change the context.

See also http://jsfiddle.net/KtXpV/ for an example.